# Money denomination program for ATM in js that would be flexible to handle and dispense money in minimum notes

Tags: javascript, typescript

the code should be able to handle any amount up to 20000, For example, suppose the Entered amount is 2600 when the balance in the card is 3000. Will output following :
New Balance - 400
Notes:
2000 * 1
500 * 1
100 * 1

(only three banknotes 2000, 500, 100) and the cash limit is 20000

I am new in the javascript world, and I am not able to write the code, could anyone help me out??? please!

```
var h = 5;
var f = 2;
var t = 1;


var ifAmtLessThn2000 = ifAmtLessThn2000(n) {
    var temp;
    if (n < 500) {
        h += (n / 100);
        return {
            h
        }
    } else if (n >= 500 && n < 2000) {
        f += n / 500;
        h += (n - 500) / 100;
        return {
            h,
            f
        }
    } else {
        temp = n - 1500;
        if (temp < 500) {
            h += (temp / 100);
            return {
                h
            }
            console.log('hundred : ' + h);
        } else {
            f += 1;
            h += (temp - 500) / 100;
            console.log('five hundred : ' + f);
            console.log('hundred : ' + h);
            return {
                f,
                h
            }
        }
    }
}


var ifAmtGreaterthan2000 = (n) => {
    var h = 0;
    var f = 0;
    var t = 0;
    var tt = 0;
    var temp;

    if (n < 2000) {
        tt += (n / 2000);
    }
    else if (n >= 2000 && n < 10000) {
        f += n / 500;
        h += (n - 500) / 100;
    }
    else {
        temp = n - 1500;
        if (temp < 500) {
            h += (temp / 100);
        }
        else {
            f += 1;
            h += (temp - 500) / 100;
        }
    }
}




var checkAmt = (n) => {
    if (n < 100 || (n % 100) > 0) {
        console.log("Invalid Amount : less than 100 ");
    } else {
        if (n > 20000) {
            console.log("ATM Cash Limit exceeds.");
        } else {
            if (n <= 2500) {
                ifAmtLessThn2500(n);
                console.log(h + " x 100");
                console.log(f + " x 500");
            } else {
                temp = n - 2500;
                t += temp / 1000;
                if (temp > 500)
                    temp = temp - (1000 * (t - 1));
                ifAmtLessThn2500(temp);
                console.log(h + " x 100");
                console.log(f + " x 500");
                console.log(t + " x 1000");
            }
        }
    }

}

checkAmt(2500);
```

Sorry for a dumb program, but I need help please can anyone give me a solution in typeScript code, returning the req denomination in array!!

Comment: Please explain what's wrong with your program (input, current output, expected output)

Comment: Actually, I am new to js, so googled for it, found one code in java, tried to convert it into js .. but nothing works!!

Comment: @user202729 any help??

Comment: Not until you make your question better. What exactly doesn't work? If there are error messages, what are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
amtArray = [2000, 500, 100];  // the denomination you want to find.

 for (let i = 0; i < this.amtArray.length; i++) {
            this.resultArray.push(Math.floor(total / this.amtArray[i]));
            // Get the new total
            total = total % this.amtArray[i];
        }
        var twothousands_notes = this.resultArray[0];
        var fivehundred_notes = this.resultArray[1];
        var hundred_notes = this.resultArray[2];

        console.log('calculated amt : ' + '100 : ' +
            hundred_notes + '   500 :  ' +
            fivehundred_notes + '  2000 :  ' +
            twothousands_notes);
```

Based on the amount you can adjust the logic.

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 4):

```js
const withdraw = (amount) => {
  let hundredNotes = 0;
  let fiftyNotes = 0;
  let twentyNotes = 0;

  while (amount >= 20) {
    if (
      amount >= 100 &&
      ((amount % 100) % 50 === 0 || (amount % 100) % 20 === 0)
    ) {
      amount -= 100;
      hundredNotes++;
    } else if (
      amount >= 50 &&
      ((amount % 50) % 100 === 0 || (amount % 50) % 20 === 0)
    ) {
      amount -= 50;
      fiftyNotes++;
    } else {
      amount -= 20;
      twentyNotes++;
    }
  }
  return [hundredNotes, fiftyNotes, twentyNotes];
};


console.log(withdraw(230));

console.log(withdraw(250));
```

Comment: So smart idea! Wow!!

Answer (score 1):

this would cover all your cases

```
function dispenseCase (inputAmount) {
 var notes = [];
 var balance = 3000;

  if(inputAmount !== 0 && inputAmount % 100 == 0 && inputAmount <= balance) {
    var notes2000 = Math.round(inputAmount / 2000);
    var notes500 = Math.round((inputAmount - (notes2000 * 2000)) / 500 );
    var notes100 = Math.round((inputAmount - ((notes2000 * 2000) + (notes500 * 500))) / 100);

   notes.push(notes2000);
   notes.push(notes500);
   notes.push(notes100);

   console.log("balance in you account = ", balance - inputAmount);
   console.log(notes);
  }
  else if (inputAmount > balance) {
   console.log("Insufficient balance in your account");
  }
  else if ( inputAmount % 100 != 0 || inputAmount < 100 ) {
   console.log( "Invalid amount entered, amount should be multiples of 100");
}
}

dispenseCase(2600);
```

Comment: No @koushik Reddy U , after 3000 this code is returning -1,-2 values, which is not optimal..

Comment: check this jsfiddle, see the output in browser console.

https://jsfiddle.net/koushikru/tgu22j58/1/#&togetherjs=4ba1U3dkNJ

Answer (score 1):

ATM denomination program in Javascript.

Here, It'll find the minimum number of notes of different denominations that sum the entered amount. Starting from the highest denomination note to the lowest notes.

```
function countCurrency(amount) {
  var notes = [2000, 500, 200, 100];
  var noteCounter = [0, 0, 0, 0];

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (amount >= notes[i]) {
      noteCounter[i] = Math.floor(amount / notes[i]);
      amount = amount - noteCounter[i] * notes[i];
    }
  }
  // Print notes denomination
  console.log("Denomination Count:");
  for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    if (noteCounter[j] !== 0) {
      console.log(notes[j] + " : " + noteCounter[j]);
    }
  }
}

countCurrency(3300);
```

Here is the working example
https://codesandbox.io/s/atm-denomination-javascript-o0wb4?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

this would print the number of notes in a 2000, 500, 100 order for the amount you enter

```
function dispenseCase (inputAmount) {
 var notes = [];

  if(inputAmount !== 0) {
    var notes2000 = Math.round(inputAmount / 2000);
    var notes500 = Math.round((inputAmount - (notes2000 * 2000)) / 500 );
    var notes100 = Math.round((inputAmount - ((notes2000 * 2000) + (notes500 * 500))) / 100);

   notes.push(notes2000);
   notes.push(notes500);
   notes.push(notes100);

   console.log(notes);
  }
}

dispenseCase(2600);
```

hope this helps

Comment: with your function if the `inputAmount` more than 3000 it would be having calculation problem

Comment: yes. you can add few more checkes for this where am checking inputAmount !==0

Comment: editted your answer, using `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round`, sorry if you do mind

Comment: thanks @KoushikReddyU , but this is not the solution ... It sholud handle  every amount upto 20000 and should display the appropriate denomination...

Answer (score 0):

```
//ATM Cash Denominations //Cash Input Value Already been Provided in this method // You may use a input stream method to input a user input value

public class Denominations
{
 public static void main(String args[])//throws IOException
 {

 int notes[]={5000,2000,1000,500,100}; //storing all the denominations in an array
 int amount = 27000;

 int copy=amount; //Making a copy of the amount
 int totalNotes=0,count=0;

 System.out.println("\nATM CASH DENOMINATIONS: \n");

 for(int i=0;i<5;i++) //Since there are 5 different types of notes, hence we check for each note.
 {
 count=amount/notes[i]; // counting number of notes[i] notes
 if(count!=0) //printing that denomination if the count is not zero
 {
 System.out.println(notes[i]+"\tx\t"+count+"\t= "+notes[i]*count);
 }
 totalNotes=totalNotes+count; //finding the total number of notes
 amount=amount%notes[i]; //finding the remaining amount whose denomination is to be found
 }

 System.out.println("--------------------------------");
 System.out.println("TOTAL\t\t\t= "+copy); //printing the total amount
 System.out.println("--------------------------------");
 System.out.println("Total Number of Notes\t= "+totalNotes); //printing the total number of notes
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let sumToDenominate=Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
let billsValues = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5,1];

let restAfterDenomination = [];
let billsNumber = [];



function denomination(sum, billsValues) {



printInitialValue( sumToDenominate, billsValues);

initializeArray( sumToDenominate, billsValues);


for (let i = 1; i <= billsValues.length; i++) {

    if (restAfterDenomination[i - 1] > 0 || restAfterDenomination < billsNumber[i]) {

        billsNumber.push(Math.floor(restAfterDenomination[i - 1] / billsValues[i]));

        console.log(`bill's number of `, billsValues[i], "=>", billsNumber[i]);

        restAfterDenomination.push(restAfterDenomination[i - 1] - (billsNumber[i] * billsValues[i]));


    } else {
        console.log(`rest is less than smallest bill or equal to 0`);
        billsNumber.push(0);
        // break;
    }
}



}

function printInitialValue(amount, billsValue) {
console.log("Denomination sumToDenominate: ", amount);

console.log("____________");
for (const logEntry of billsValue) {
    console.log(logEntry);
}
console.log("__________");
}

function initializeArray(amount, billsValues) {


billsNumber.push(Math.floor(amount / billsValues[0]));

console.log(`bill's number of`, billsValues[0], "=>", billsNumber[0]);

restAfterDenomination.push(amount - (billsNumber[0] * billsValues[0]));


denomination(sumToDenominate,billsValues);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.