# ATM withdrawal algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, limit

How does an ATM withdrawal algorithm work?

The code to get money from the ATM should work like this:

```js
// count of nominals in ATM
let limits = {
  1000: 5,
  500: 2,
  100: 5,
  50: 100,
  30: 6
}

let getMoney = (amount, limits) => {
  ...
};

console.log(getMoney(1000, limits)); // {1000: 1}
console.log(getMoney(230, limits)); // {} | i need {100: 2, 30: 1}
console.log(getMoney(200, limits)); // {100: 2}
console.log(getMoney(150, limits)); // {50: 3} | i need {100: 1, 50: 1}
console.log(getMoney(120, limits)); // {30: 4}
```

I tried, and made this:

```
let getMoney = (am, lm) => {
  Object.keys(lm).map( k => {
    if(lm[k] && am / k >= 1 && am % k === 0)
      if(lm[k] > am / k)
        r[k] = am / k;
  });
};
```

...but the result is not correct:

```
console.log( getMoney(1000, limits) ); // {1000: 1}
console.log( getMoney(230, limits) ); // {} | i need {100: 2, 30: 1}
console.log( getMoney(200, limits) ); // {100: 2}
console.log( getMoney(150, limits) ); // {50: 3} | i need {100: 1, 50: 1}
console.log( getMoney(120, limits) ); // {30: 4}
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: please add your try. what does not work? is it for school?

Comment: Also post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I don't want to waste time to guess what mean of dict `limits`, plz add some comment to explain your algorithm

Comment: @MoreFreeze i have added a comment

Comment: Thiat is a snapback problem, your algorithm doesn't work here.


There are many probleams in your algorithm: 

1. You don't do `am -= am / k * k`, if client need withdraw 230, and you find you can provide 2 pieces of 100, the rest you need calculate is 30 instead 230.
2. `Greedy is not good` here. It is easy to make some counterexample. Think about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm assumes that if there is a solution, then that solution will take the most of the highest available denomination that still fits the remaining amount. This would work for some sets of denominations, like the common one (1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1), but not for the one in your example.

This is a variant of the [change making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) and is a "hard" problem, in that you must potentially try a huge number of combinations. One way is to at least give precedence to attempts that take a lot of the higher valued denominations, and only try alternatives when those do not lead to a solution.

You could code it like this:

```js
let getMoney = (amount, limits) => {
    let recur = (amount, nominals) => {
        if (amount == 0) return {}; // success
        if (!nominals.length) return; // failure
        let nominal = nominals[0];
        let count = Math.min(limits[nominal], Math.floor(amount / nominal));
        for (let i = count; i >= 0; i--) {
            let result = recur(amount - i*nominal, nominals.slice(1));
            if (result) return i ? { [nominal]: i, ...result } : result;
        }
    }
    return recur(amount, Object.keys(limits).map(Number).sort((a,b) => b - a));
};

// count of nominals in ATM
let limits = { 1000: 5, 500: 2, 100: 5, 50: 100, 30: 6 }

console.log(getMoney(1000, limits)); // {1000: 1}
console.log(getMoney(230, limits)); // {30: 1, 100: 2}
console.log(getMoney(200, limits)); // {100: 2}
console.log(getMoney(150, limits)); // {50: 1, 100: 1}
console.log(getMoney(120, limits)); // {30: 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

ATM denomination program in Javascript.

Here, It'll find the minimum number of notes of different denominations that sum the entered amount. Starting from the highest denomination note to the lowest notes.

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66456375/9248245. This might helps others